# Error on the super.onActivityResult() why?

Tags: android, android-activity, superclass, uses-feature

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode,resultCode,data)

    if (requestCode == Selectedimage && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null) {

        Uri pickedImage = data.getData();
        Intent send= new Intent(Selection.this,Imagepage.class);
        send.putExtra("pickedImage",pickedImage.toString());
        startActivity(send);
    }
}
```

what is the use of adding that `super.onActivityResult` line ? and also when am adding that, its showing some error.

Comment: what is the error ? is that a crash if so post the crash log

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, if you get an error - always show logcat. Secondly, if this method is declared in the class extending `Activity`, there is no need to call `super` there since this method is empty in the `Activity` class:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

The `onActivityResult()` is a little like `onOptionMenuSelected()`, in the way that:

1. Based on the params, you can tell if this function call should be processed in this level
2. if so, process with it and return (true)
3. if not, just call the super class's implementation

Therefore, in your Fragment's `onActivityResult()`, you should first check if the `requestCode` meets what you set before, if so, deal with the data and return. If not, just return with `super.onActivityResult()`.

A simple sample may look like:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    switch (requestCode) {
    case SELECT_FILE_TO_UPLOAD:
        // upload a file
        return;

    case SELECT_FILE_TO_DELETE:
        // delete a file
        return;

    default:
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The call does not really do anything ([link to source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.3.1_r1/android/app/Activity.java#Activity.onActivityResult%28int,int,android.content.Intent%29)) so you can omit it if it's giving problems.

The fact that it does is weird considering the empty super implementation though.